# Setting the delegate when using canDisplayBannerAds

Tags: ios, ios7, iad

I've been struggling to get (banner) `iAds` to display correctly in the `iPhone`, and in an `iPad` merely displaying the `iPhone` app (scaled up). I **still** don't know how to fix this, and haven't found anyone else having this problem.

Then I noticed that in `iOS7` there's a way to automate using banner ads in an app, by setting:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds=YES:
```

... In the `viewDidLoad` method. This seemed like a cool, streamlined way to implement banners, but haven't figured out how to set the delegate when using this automated method. Can one do this, or do you have to do the more manual method of creating an `adBannerView`, setting the delegate, and then implementing the delegate methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not display iAds in compatibility mode on the iPad.

Your app must be universal for iAds to display.

[Technical Note TN2264: iAd Implementation Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827-CH1-CREATE_UNIVERSAL_APPS)

Additionally, the delegate methods are not forwards to your application if you are using  `self.canDisplayBannerAds`. [See here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/922541#922541)

Comment: What's strange is that they serve test ads to the iPad Simulator (or my test machine). The problem is that the banner appears white, but is probably just scaled up weirdly. When I click on the banner, I get the test fullscreen ad, again scaled up strangely. Thanks for the delegate info, though.

Comment: Just tested myself in the iPad simulator and I didn't get any iAds, but I did in the iPhone sim. In production I can guarantee you won't get any live ads, I have first hand experience of this. Best thing you can do is fallback to something like admob or create a universal app.

Comment: I'm going that way too, I have had quite a few issues with using other ad networks. Hope I've answered your question and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I will have to use the old fashioned way. I first try iAd, then if it fails, try another network. Supporting iOS6 anyway, so easier to keep it the same as before.